# Where is word spacing determined and how do I edit it?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-forge

I am editing a font in Font Forge but it seems there is no variable or property for word spacing. Applications all render this font with far too wide word spacing which led me to assume this was a variable in the font file itself, but I can't see it.
So, where is word spacing determined and how do I edit it?

Comment: I have no idea what is your written language and does it need something special between the words. Here in the west we have a space character between 2 adjacent words for that purpose. Try to define the width of your word separator character if such item is used where you live..

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust side-bearing values with the keyboard.

One method of adjusting metric values quickly and accurately in FontForge is by using the **up**, **down**, **left**, and **right** keys of a keyboard.

The up and down keys are used to increment / decrement values and **Alt + Up**, **Alt + Down**, **Alt + Left** and **Alt + Right** are used for *navigating* around the different value fields of the Metrics Window.

For a better understanding please refer to this [link](http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/Line_Spacing.html).

Thank You!

Comment: Ok so I guess you meant adjusting metric values for the space character

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the answer is there is a single 'space' character to the left of the exclamation mark in Unicode position 32. Although there is no actual character, the width of the space can be set here.